# Pyomo : summation constraint on row level <= 1

Tags: python, constraints, pyomo

During the setup of a Concretemodel in Pyomo I have the need to set up the following constraint
sum_of_perc[times,companies] <= 1

Currently I have the following code

`m.cons.add(sum(m.key_optimized[t, c] for t, c in itertools.product(m.times, m.companies)) <= 1)`

The itertools.product allows me to cycle through the different times and companies.

Think of the following hypothetical/random example of the 2 dimensional array. Each row is a t and each element is c

```
[0.1 , 0.4 , 0.0 , 0.5] <= 1
[0.2 , 0.2 , 0.6 , 0.0] <= 1
```

Currently my constraint tries to get the whole 2D matrix to be <= 1. But I want this to be a summation on a t level or row level. Example result of my code gives the following. This adds up to exactly 1.

```
(0, 0) 0.34
(0, 1) 0.42
(0, 2) 0.0
(0, 3) 0.16
(1, 0) 0.005
(1, 1) 0.075
(1, 2) 0.0
(1, 3) 0.0
```

Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will answer your question...

First, if you want to replicate what you just did without `itertools` it is easy to make the full cross product of 2 sets.  See first part below.

If you are making a constraint *for each* of something, you should immediately think of setting up a function-rule combo that will call the function *for each* member of the set(s) that you provide in the Constraint.  See the latter part below.

```
In [22]: from pyomo.environ import *                                            

In [23]: m = ConcreteModel('example')                                           

In [24]: m.a = Set(initialize=[1,2,3])                                          

In [25]: m.b = Set(initialize=list('abc'))                                      

In [26]: from pyomo.environ import *                                            

In [27]: m = ConcreteModel('example')                                           

In [28]: m.A = Set(initialize=[1,2,3])                                          

In [29]: m.B = Set(initialize=list('abc'))                                      

In [30]: m.X = Var(m.A, m.B, domain=NonNegativeReals)                           

In [31]: # example constraint for "the whole matrix" like you have now          

In [32]: m.C1 = Constraint(expr=sum(m.X[a,b] for a in m.A for b in m.B)<=1)     

In [33]: m.pprint()                                                             
3 Set Declarations
    A : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {1, 2, 3}
    B : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'a', 'b', 'c'}
    X_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    A*B :    9 : {(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (3, 'c')}

1 Var Declarations
    X : Size=9, Index=X_index
        Key      : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        (1, 'a') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (1, 'b') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (1, 'c') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (2, 'a') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (2, 'b') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (2, 'c') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (3, 'a') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (3, 'b') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (3, 'c') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

1 Constraint Declarations
    C1 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body                                                                           : Upper : Active
        None :  -Inf : X[1,a] + X[1,b] + X[1,c] + X[2,a] + X[2,b] + X[2,c] + X[3,a] + X[3,b] + X[3,c] :   1.0 :   True

5 Declarations: A B X_index X C1

In [34]: # OK, now if we want to make the row summation "for each a in m.A"     

In [35]: # we want to use a function-rule combo is easiest...                   

In [36]: def sum_over_b(m, a): 
    ...:     return sum(m.X[a,b] for b in m.B) <= 1 
    ...:                                                                        

In [37]: m.C2 = Constraint(m.A, rule=sum_over_b)                                

In [38]: m.C2.pprint()                                                          
C2 : Size=3, Index=A, Active=True
    Key : Lower : Body                     : Upper : Active
      1 :  -Inf : X[1,a] + X[1,b] + X[1,c] :   1.0 :   True
      2 :  -Inf : X[2,a] + X[2,b] + X[2,c] :   1.0 :   True
      3 :  -Inf : X[3,a] + X[3,b] + X[3,c] :   1.0 :   True

In [39]:
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this very extensive answer! This perfectly clears up the confusion! I need to get used to using rules. Seems like a more efficient way of setting up the constraints compared to the way I was doing it.
I need to put some more time in learning the Pyomo syntax.

I introduced the rule to my code and the result was exactly what I was expecting!